# Copy random file from one folder to another with unique name

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I want to copy random "my file.jpg" from \source to \output with date added to the end - "my file 11-22-2019.jpg"

This is working perfectly:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\source
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set /A n+=1
    set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set "dummy=!random!"
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" C:\output
```

But how to add the date to the filename?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put your variable `"!file[%rand%]!"` into a `FOR` command to split apart the base file name and extension. Open up a command prompt and type: `FOR /?` to read the help.  The very bottom section shows you how to use the command modifiers to get the base file name and extension split out.

Comment: Do you want the current date or the date the file was last written added to the file name?

Comment: The current date :)

Comment: Lots of questions and answers here that have already discussed your topic. Should be able to find your answer with a simple search.